# Index the first and the last n elements of a list

Tags: python, list

the first n and the last n element of the python list

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

can be indexed by the expressions

```
print l[:3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
print l[-3:]
[8, 9, 10]
```

is there a way to combine both in a single expression, i.e index the first n and the last n elements using one indexing expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just concatenate the results:

```
l[:3] + l[-3:]
```

There is no dedicated syntax to combine disjoint slices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats the solution I was looking for. I marked it as answer, since it was the first of several similar solutions.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you can use:

```
l[:3] + l [-3:]
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer, thats actually the simple solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean like:

```
l[:3]+l[-3:]
```

then using variable:

```
l[:x]+l[-y:]
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer, thats actually the simple solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If it is allowed to change list, You can use this:

```
del(a[n:-n])
```

If not, create new list and then do this.

```
b = [x for x in a]
del(b[n:-n])
```